# Can we detect by adding Addlistner event to map if user clicked on maps inbuilt buttons such as zoom-in, zoom-out and expand etc. POV-MapMyIndia

Tags: javascript, reactjs, maps

`map.addListener('click', function (e) { console.log('click',e);}); map.addListener('mousemove', function () { console.log('mousemove');}); map.addListener('mouseDown', function () { console.log('mouseDown');});`

I expect button names in event.target so that i can add events when i particular button is clicked

Comment: What "map" API are you using? Google Maps?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Map my India i am using